# Howt to authenticate linkedin rest api?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make an web app using linkedin rest api. 
I'm following [these](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) instructions. I have done step-1.
I have created an application on [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps). I got **Client ID** and **Client Secret** for that app.

I'm stuck with step-2. How do I get **USER_TOKEN** and **USER_SECRET** for my app? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @pratibha I'm also stuck in step 2 and I'm using javascript as client side

Answer (score 0):

Try following this. For Python linkedin lib.

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

request_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST")
if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception("Invalid response %s." % resp['status'])

print content

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Requesr Token:",  "\n"
print "- oauth_token        = %s" % request_token['oauth_token'], "\n"
print "- oauth_token_secret = %s" % request_token['oauth_token_secret'], "\n"

authorize_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize'
print "Go to the following link in your browser:", "\n"
print "%s?oauth_token=%s" % (authorize_url, request_token['oauth_token']), "\n"

accepted = 'n'
while accepted.lower() == 'n':
    accepted = raw_input('Have you authorized me? (y/n) ')
oauth_verifier = raw_input('What is the PIN? ')

access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'],        request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Access Token:", "\n"
print "- oauth_token        = %s" % access_token['oauth_token'], "\n"
print "- oauth_token_secret = %s" % access_token['oauth_token_secret']
print "You may now access protected resources using the access tokens above."
```

Comment: Hello, I get Message  
Exception: Invalid response 400.    
 => Can you help plz ?